# Store accessor for nested JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, jsonb

I have the model "Organization" that stores all information related to an organization. There is a field of type JSONB named "integrations" that stores information pertaining to all external service integrations that an organization has.

How do I use store accessors to access information stored in nested JSON, for example :

```
{
 "mailchimp": {"api_key":"vsvsvef", "list_id":"12345"},
 "sendgrid" : {"username":"msdvsv", "password":"123456"}
}
```

I know I can access mailchimp with store accessors like this :

```
store_accessor :integrations, :mailchimp
```

How can I easily access the api_key of mailchimp?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're right, unfortunately `store_accessor` does not allow you to access nested keys. The reason is that `store_accessor` is basically just a shortcut which defines getter and setter methods:

```
# here is a part of store_accessor method code, you can take a look at
# full implementation at
# http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods/store_accessor
_store_accessors_module.module_eval do
  keys.each do |key|
    # here we define a setter for each passed key
    define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
      write_store_attribute(store_attribute, key, value)
    end

    # and here goes the getter
    define_method(key) do
      read_store_attribute(store_attribute, key)
    end
  end
end
```

So, your options here are:

1. To implement your own set of getter and setter methods manually:

   ```
   # somewhere in your model
   def mailchimp_api_key
     self.mailchimp["api_key"]
   end

   def mailchimp_api_key= value
     self.mailchimp["api_key"] = value
   end
   ```

   This solves a problem, but you'd have to write lots of this repeatedly for each of nested attributes.
2. To write your own helper method inside of `ActiveRecord::Store::ClassMethods` module which would define the same setter and getter methods dynamically for the set of attributes you pass in. You'd have to take the basic implementation of Rails `store_accessor` and add an additional hash keys iteration to it. Not sure if this is going to be an easy one, but would definitely be interesting to see shared as a gem.
3. Leave Rails itself and use the power of postgres `json` type support with some pure `SQL` code. For example, you can access `api_key` attribute with something like that:

   ```
   SELECT integrations->'mailchimp'->>'api_key' as mailchimp_api_key FROM your_table_name;
   ```

   More on postgres json queries can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using [the Attribute API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute)

```rb
store_accessor :integrations, :mailchimp
store_accessor :mailchimp, :api_key, :list_id
attribute :mailchimp, :json # :jsonb also works if you're using a PG column of that type for `integrations`
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing. As @twonegatives indicated, store_accessor won't help us. But I did find the #dig method to work pretty well for getting the data. So...

```
#somewhere in Organization model
def api_key
  integrations.dig("mailchimp", "api_key")
end

def username
  integrations.dig("sendgrid", "username")
end
```