# Setting form to group hash key/ value pairs in my array key of my JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hstore, jsonb

I have an array key in my JSONB column which I want to store hashes in.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :data, :foos

  # foo = []
end

class ProductForm
  #
end

form_for @product_form do |f|

# stuff

f.fields_for :foos do |ff|
  <fieldset class="foos">
    ff.input :bat # options
    ff.input :buzz
  </fieldset>
end
link_to_add_fields # args
end
```

But I want to make `fields_for` dynamically accepts multiple foos, but before I just write out the raw html by hand I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic way.

(I suspect a solution which works in `hstore` should work for `jsonb` as well`)

Comment: look at this articles, I believe they will be helpful. [nested inputs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-inputs-for-key-value-hash-attributes), then  see [nested json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694695/store-accessor-for-nested-json) and finally [using activemodel to build nested forms](https://coderwall.com/p/kvsbfa/nested-forms-with-activemodel-model-objects). If you have solved it yourself, then post an answer.

Comment: I went with something pretty much described in the last article